# Karate API Tests - Using xml instead of json

Tags: java, karate

I am able to use json file to have my credentials parsed in the feature file.
eg:

```
 * def credentials = read('classpath:credentials.json')
 * header Authorization = call read('classpath:basic-auth.js') { username: '#(credentials.user)', password: '#(credentials.pwd)' }
```

Here is the credentials json file:

```
{
  user: 'abc',
  pwd: 'def'
}
```

However, When I try using an XML file instead, I am not able to parse it through:

Credentials xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <credentials>  
   <user>abc</user>
   <pwd>def</pwd>
 </credentials>
```

I changed the feature file as:

```
 * def credentials = read('classpath:credentials.xml')
 * header Authorization = call read('classpath:basic-auth.js') { username: '#(<credentials><user></credentials>)', password: '#(<credentials><pwd></credentials>)' }
```

Do i need to make any changes in the way I am parsing the xml ? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedded expressions have to use the 'dot notation'. The good news is that this can operate on XML, so try this:

```
* def creds = read('classpath:credentials.xml')
* header Authorization = call read('classpath:basic-auth.js') { username: '#(creds.credentials.user)', password: '#(creds.credentials.pwd)' }
```

Within Karate I would advise sticking to JSON as far as possible unless you are forced to use XML because you are re-using something external to your project or testing SOAP or XML payloads. But if you really are doing a lot of XML handling, refer to [this set of examples](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature) for ideas.

edited - since I missed the extra XML root `credentials` in the expressions.

Comment: I wanted to go with json file but when generating the cucumber report, it is picking up the credentials.json file and returning the following error:

net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: File ‘**/jobs/#####/jobs/####/builds/5/cucumber-html-reports/.cache/test-classes/credentials.json' is not proper Cucumber report!

Comment: Huh !? This should never happen. Set the output folder for the report XML and JSON to something sensible like "target/surefire-reports": https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

Comment: I already set the karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
Also, through jenkins I am running it in parallel:
test -Dcucumber.options="--plugin junit:target/cucumber-junit.xml --tags ~@ignore" -Dtest=TestParallel -DargLine=-Dkarate.env=qa

Comment: Then I have no idea. No one has ever reported something like this. Is this happening in your local dev env ? You must be mixing up the cucumber reporting plugin in your Jenkins or something. Start with a clean project ! Or stick to just Jenkins JUnit reporting. Skip the junit cucumber.options. All the best.

Comment: Figured out, it was a path issue in jenkins. Thanks for all your help. I am able to generate reports irrespective of json or xml. Thanks @Peter Thomas

Comment: @Saurabh Great ! Do consider accepting and up-voting answers, this helps to sustain the quality of responses on Stack Overflow.